# How to send an email using smtp over local host? asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, email, smtp, localhost

I have implemented a contact form to a web app but when I try to send the email I get JavaScript runtime errors, http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/371417/Send-Mail-Contact-Form-using-ASP-NET-and-Csharp at `line 37` which is an empty line.

Does anyone have an idea as to what is wrong with my implementation or do I have to change some settings to test it on local host?

```
//calls the SendMail() and resets the textboxes
    protected void sendBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            //here on button click what will done 
            SendMail();
            confirmationLbl.Text = "Your email has been sent to customer support.";
            confirmationLbl.Visible = true;
            subjectTbx.Text = "";
            emailTbx.Text = "";
            nameTbx.Text = "";
            questionTbx.Text = "";
        }
        catch (Exception ex) {

            confirmationLbl.Text = "Your email has failed to send,please check your connection.";
            Console.WriteLine("IOException source: {0}", ex.Message );


        }

//line 37 is here, which is blank
    }

    //method to compose email from textboxes
    protected void SendMail()
    {
        // Gmail Address from where you send the mail
        var fromAddress = emailTbx.Text.ToString(); 
        // any address where the email will be sending
        var toAddress = "brianDoe@gmail.com";
        //Password of your gmail address
        const string fromPassword = "Password";
        // Passing the values and make a email formate to display
        string subject = subjectTbx.Text.ToString();
        string body = "From: " + nameTbx.Text + "\n";
        body += "Email: " + emailTbx.Text + "\n";
        body += "Subject: " + subjectTbx.Text + "\n";
        body += "Question: \n" + questionTbx.Text + "\n";
        // smtp settings
        var smtp = new System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient();
        {
            smtp.Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
            smtp.Port = 587;
            smtp.EnableSsl = true;
            smtp.DeliveryMethod = System.Net.Mail.SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
            smtp.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(fromAddress, fromPassword);
            smtp.Timeout = 20000;
        }
        // Passing values to smtp object
        smtp.Send(fromAddress, toAddress, subject, body);

    }
```

Comment: Your email address is in there, i.e., for all to see on here.

Comment: You get JavaScript errors in your C# code? Very weird (tip: Try looking at line 37 in your JavaScript... also try posting the error; it's quite important to the debugging process).

Comment: I don't think his last name is Doe

Comment: You're right, it isn't......... because he changed it - not relevant to continue discussing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should check your parsed HTML for JavaScript error rather than C# code. Also, make sure POP/IMAP access is enabled in Gmail under settings.

[image]

Comment: I just changed my email settings but I'm not sure what you mean by check the parsed HTML, Where would I find this code? Is it the Html file for that page?

Comment: The aspx and the C# code is parsed into HTML and JavaScript for displaying in the browser. When you open the page, right click and select View Page Source (in Chrome) and check line 37.

Comment: Also I'm not sure if this is the error causing the problem, because the exception `ex` is thrown at the button click.

Comment: Code seems to be fine. You do need to enable POP/IMAP inside Gmail to make it work. Also, what is the exception you get, when you click on the button ? [Chk this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32260/sending-email-in-net-through-gmail)

Comment: Okay so I printed the exception message being caught and it states this: `The SMTP server requires a secure connection or the client was not authenticated. The server response was: 5.5.1 Authentication Required`

Comment: Add `smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = false;` to the code.

Comment: Still getting the same error after adding that code.. Any ideas as to what it could be?

Comment: Are you running this on a remote server ? Sometimes Gmail blocks the connection, because the request is received from an unknown IP. If that is the case - Login to Gmail first from the remote server, you are trying to the app to familiarize Gmail with that particular IP for your account.

Comment: I'm running from visual studio on local host, I tried that too but it didn't work.. I'm guessing if the website was hosted the email should send though?